# Rails app trying to update a nonexistent column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

This is on Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.19. I'm not super experienced with Rails. Today I started having this issue ONLY on our live server, everything works fine on the development server.

Whenever I try to give a **publication** model new **tags**, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "taggings_count" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "tags" SET "taggings_count" = OALESCE("taggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "tags"."id" = 47:  
  app/controllers/publications_controller.rb:162:in 'block in update'
  app/controllers/publications_controller.rb:161:in 'update'
```

and line 162 of the controller is:

```
def update
    @publication = Publication.find(params[:id])
    if params[:clear_virtual_performances]
      @publication.virtual_performances.each {|vp| vp.destroy}
    end

    if media_id = params["selected_media"]
      pub_ids = @publication.publication_media_ids
      PublicationMedia.update(@publication.publication_media_ids, [{:selected => false}] * pub_ids.length)
      PublicationMedia.update(media_id, :selected => true)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @publication.update_attributes(params[:publication])  // <-------------------
        expire_fragments
        flash[:notice] = 'Publication was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(:action => 'show') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        load_extra_vars_for_edit_form
                        Category.in_slug(params[:default_category])
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @publication.errors,
                             :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, the column "taggings_count" does not exist in tags and I don't know why it would be looking to update that in the first place. In fact, the table on has the columns: **id**, **name**, **position**, **category_id**, and **tag_group_id**. Here is the tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :taggings
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :tag_group

  attr_accessible :name, :position, :category_id, :tag_group_id
end
```

If there is any more information I should give please let me know; it's vital that we get this fixed as soon as possible. All I need is for the error not to happen, even if that means creating a dummy column or something.

Comment: Please post the respective `form` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a `counter_cache` attribute defined in Tagging, something like `belongs_to :publication, counter_cache: true`. That's causing the counter to automagically increment.

You can either remove the `counter_cache: true` or make a migration to add the column.

Comment: Well, there was no counter_cache oddly enough, and even adding one and setting it to false didn't work. However creating the column via a migration worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Are you using a gem like acts_as_taggable_on? Maybe your Taggable class inherited from something that has the declaration.

Comment: Yes actually! That's likely where the problem came from then; the gem was probably left uninstalled for months until yesterday when I ran bundle install. Thanks!